# Javascript How to build a checkbox list that returns the values which have been checked

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build a page that will have a list of objects ex:
-obj1
-obj2
-obj3
and each will have a checkbox. I am having trouble building a function that will return the value of all the boxes which have been checked.

Here is my code, I feel like I am close but it does not work:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("objs").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
OBJ1: <input type="checkbox" id="obj1" value="1"> 
OBJ2: <input type="checkbox" id="obj2" value="2"> 
OBJ3: <input type="checkbox" id="obj3" value="3">
<p>Click the "Try it" button to display the value of the value attribute of the checkbox.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Refresh</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: `getElementById("objs")` What element is this supposed to get?

Comment: It is supposed to get the ID of a specified input but I am trying to get it to be available for all of the input objects with no success

Comment: @j08691 Unfortunately, the link you have provided answers a different case.

Comment: @Kinduser How do you figure?

Comment: @j08691 *The link* is about returning checked boxes as whole elements, not just their specified attributes.

Comment: @Kinduser mmmm I'm on the fence about this but alright, I'll reopen

Comment: @j08691 Thanks for your kindness. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll` to get all checkboxes that are checked, using a valid selector (instead of your "objs", which is not valid, because there is no such element):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var selected = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:checked")) 
                      .map(function(checkbox) { return checkbox.value; })
                      .join(' ');

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = selected;
}
```

```html
OBJ1: <input type="checkbox" id="obj1" value="1"> 
OBJ2: <input type="checkbox" id="obj2" value="2"> 
OBJ3: <input type="checkbox" id="obj3" value="3">
<p>Click the "Try it" button to display the value of the value attribute of the checkbox.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Refresh</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const elems = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
  console.log(Array.from(elems).map(c => c.value));
})
```

```html
OBJ1: <input type="checkbox" id="obj1" value="1"> 
OBJ2: <input type="checkbox" id="obj2" value="2"> 
OBJ3: <input type="checkbox" id="obj3" value="3">
<p>Click the "Try it" button to display the value of the value attribute of the checkbox.</p>
<button id='btn'>Refresh</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are looking for in terms of output but this gets you the values of the checkboxes that have been checked

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("objs");
  var s='';
  for (var i = 0;i<x.length;i++){
      if (x[i].checked) s = s + x[i].value;
  }
  
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = s;
}
```

```html
OBJ1: <input type="checkbox" class="objs" value="1"> 
OBJ2: <input type="checkbox" class="objs" value="2"> 
OBJ3: <input type="checkbox" class="objs" value="3">
<p>Click the "Try it" button to display the value of the value attribute of the checkbox.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Refresh</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```